# How to publish my github repository on readthedocs?

Tags: git, read-the-docs

To test, I created a library on github, access address:    https://github.com/zibuyule/test2.
On readthedocs.org entered my github account and build the latest version.
On readthedocs.org My address is: https://readthedocs.org/projects/test-zibuyule/.
Click on the "read the document" shows 404 error page. Try the afternoon still not been resolved.
Who have successfully posted on readthedocs.org, whether under the advice. I feel this thing is still very good, hope to use it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. Just put the `.md` documentation files inside a `docs` folder in your repository and it will work.

Extract from their [documentation](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builds.html#mkdocs):

> We will look inside a doc or docs directory first, and then default to the top-level of your documentation.

It seems that it is incorrect - top-level folder is not scanned for `.md` files, so you have to use `docs` folder